# How to change font color mid-sentence

Tags: html, css

What is the correct way to change the color or font face for a single word or set of words within a sentence? I am using Twitter Bootstrap and want to inherit all the attributes of the `<div>`'s class, but only tweak them slightly.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Going off of `Chords` comment, you can create a `<span>` tag that surrounds the text you want to change. You can easily add multiple classes to a single span to achieve just the look you want as well.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR6Pt/) to show how you can use multiple classes on a single span.

**CSS**

```
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.red { color: #FF0000; }
.yellow-background { background-color: Yellow; }​
```

**HTML**

```
Here is <span class="bold">some text</span> that we are going to apply 
<span class="bold red">different styles</span> to. You can see how 
<span class="bold yellow-background">multiple classes</span> can be used to 
change the <span class="red bold yellow-background">look and feel</span> 
of the text.​
```

Comment: Bingo! This is what I'm after. I'll give this one to Jason but props to Chords for suggesting this approach. Cheers.

Comment: Just found this, and can't believe i hadnt thought of it previously.